# How do I set the width of a section based on the calculated width of another section?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

Trying to do this, but is it wrong? Below is my style and script and html that I am trying to load.

```
<style>
#bar {
    background:black;
    width:  </style><script>var barWidth = getElementByID("nav").style.width; document.write (nav);</script><style>
    height: 5px;
}
</style>

<section id="nav">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
    <a href="#">Link3</a>
    <span id="loginButton"><a href="#">Login</a></span>
    <section id="bar"></section>    
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest a `script` tag within a `style` tag. The following will accomplish your desired behavior...

```
<style>
    #bar {
        background:black;
        height: 5px;
    }
</style>


<section id="nav">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
    <a href="#">Link3</a>
    <span id="loginButton"><a href="#">Login</a></span>
    <section id="bar"></section>    
</section>


<script>
    var barWidth = getElementByID("nav").style.width;
    getElementById('bar').style.width = barWidth;
</script>
```

Comment: Oh my, I am dumb haha! Thanks Xander!

Answer (score 0):

Umm yeah you cant do that... `script` and `style` arent like switching in and out of PHP or ASP or something.

However you shoudlnt need to use js for this. if you set `#bar` to a block level element it will be the width of `#nav` by default:

```
#nav { width: 300px; }

#bar {
    background:black;
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it would be just `width:100%` as #bar is a direct descendant of #nav. However, instead of making use of a <section>-element you either should use <hr />, or better put a simple border-bottom for #nav.

The answer to the question "how to set a css rule dynamically?" might be found in the article [Totally Pwn CSS with Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript). Do not use this solution for your problem.

Comment: I am using it to do some jquery, I need it to be another section.

Comment: You can do (nearly) every width magic with pure css. Please post your real example.